# migration from local to AWS

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a spring-boot app using spring-data-jpa with mongo tables locally.  I know that I will be moving this to AWS in the near future and I am not convinced I will be able to use Mongo (Atlas) due to licensing costs, and will have to use DynamoDB. I am still researching the costs for my encryption needs, but I am concerned about all the entity work I already have in place.

My concern is my entity classes such as this, which are tied to Mongo:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "providers")
public class Provider {
...
}
```

I prefer to develop locally and then deploy, but maybe that approach is the not the best?  How do other people handle this?

Comment: spring data jpa with mongodb, I am confused!

Comment: Yes, I am using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'